Possible to remove method in ActiveRecord?
Context: Rails 7.1, only using the DB interaction layers, no web framework, no servers, etc...
I'm sure this is going to ruffle a few feathers, but I keep running into ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError regarding .model_name, on a database of vehicle information. Cars have models, and those models have names. "Just change the DB" simply isn't an option. The source DB is externally owned and managed. I literally can not modify it. And I use that DB with externally sourced data from other companies, all of whom use, expect, and understand the concept of "model_name". I physically can modify the data as I read it in, but haven't found a solution where I can make it work.
So I'm wondering if I could instead remove the .model_name method from Rails as my application loads. My application's function is local to my machine and not used elsewhere, and I don't use the Rails method anywhere. So the existence of this method is causing me problems, and removing it from models would not.
Edit:
ActiveModel::Naming instance method of .model_name https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html#method-i-model_name. Absolutely unimportant for me.
Is this doable?

while it's doable, this method is used by rails in a lot of places which would break if it returns a string instead of a ModelName object. perhaps you should use sequel or rom instead.

I'd be tempted to monkeypatch the dangerous_attribute_method? to ignore your column.

Alex, that was the nuclear option that seems more than a bit silly.

well, give it a try: ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods.instance_variable_set(:@dangerous_attribute_methods, ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods.dangerous_attribute_methods - ["model_name"])

@Alex - why not just skip the model completely at that point? If you break model_name you're breaking pretty much everything that models provide such as assocations, polymorphic routing, i18n lookup, the query interface, form bindings etc. It would be less buggy to just have a PORO that just reads/writes data by interfacing directly with the database connection. At least that way you know what actually works. I think your idea of using a different less opinionated ORM is way better.

"Is it possible?" is almost always the wrong question when it comes to Rails (if not programming in general). Ruby is an exceptionally flexible language that lets you modify almost anything at runtime and the philosophy is that the language provides you with very sharp knives and it's up to you to not cut yourself. In the case it's not only possible. It's trivial. But it doesn't make it any less of a terrible idea.

@max personally I am preferential to the adoption of the C/C++ adage: "Enough Rope to Shoot Yourself in the Foot"

@engineersmnky amazing.

It's an exceptionally bad idea.
Just because you're not referencing the method directly in your code or aware of it's importance doesn't mean that it's not a core part of the framework.
The ActiveModel::Naming API may be simple but is used by ActiveModel to interface with everything from forms, I18N, polymorphic routing etc. In short pretty much everything that makes Rails convention over configuration approach work.
In ActiveRecord the method is used to look up tables based on the class name, derive foreign keys etc.
While you could potentially explicitly configure everything and avoid some of the resulting errors what you're proposing is not removing the #model_name method - it's essentially monkeypatching over the instance method with the one created from the schema which is many times worse.
This would open a pandoras box of bugs as the model instance would still respond to #model_name and in the places where it's implicitly used as a string you would be providing Rails with junk instead of something that actually corresponds to the routes or your database tables leading to buggy and unpredicable behavior. This is a lot worse than the places where it will just straight up break because the code expects an instance of ActiveModel::Name.
ActiveRecord doesn't provide any kind of mechanism to deconflict dangerous method names and doesn't appear to be a very good choice for your application. It's a highly opinionated ORM that assumes you have full control over the database schema and follow it's conventions. If not you're just making life difficult for yourself.
Use another ORM like Sequel or add an adapter layer between your application and the database like for example replicating the database with less problematic column names.

It's doable:
# app/models/car.rb

# prevent model_name from raising a DangerousAttributeError
ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods.instance_variable_set(
  :@dangerous_attribute_methods,
  ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods.dangerous_attribute_methods - ["model_name"]
)

class Car < ApplicationRecord
  validate do
    errors.add(:model_name, :blank) if self[:model_name].blank?
  end
end

Car.new # force generation of attribute methods
Car.const_get(:GeneratedAttributeMethods).remove_method(:model_name)

with a caveat that you have to use [:model_name] to get the attribute value. Here are all of my tests:
>> Car.first[:model_name]
=> "asdf"

>> Car.first.model_name
=>
#<ActiveModel::Name:0x00007f3cb51e0de0
 @collection="cars",
 @element="car",
...

>> Car.new.save!
`<main>': Validation failed: Model name can't be blank (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)`

>> Car.new(model_name: "a").save!
=> true
>> Car.last
=> #<Car:0x00007f3cb5487300 id: 8, model_name: "a", make: nil, created_at: "2024-10-25 14:35:39.206560000 +0000", updated_at: "2024-10-25 14:35:39.206560000 +0000">


Seems like you might be able to perform the same in a less impactful way by overwriting self.dangerous_attribute_method? to exclude model_name for this class, then use alias_attribute :model, :model_name followed by def model_name; super; end although I have not tested it.

@engineersmnky oh yes, that is much simpler, except it should be def model_name; self.class.model_name; end
